# How are breadcumbs rendered on a product page Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs

How are breadcrumbs rendered on a product page Magento 2? I know it is Javascript heavy. But I am looking for answers to the below questions.

- What is the algorithm for product page breadcrumbs? How are (parent)categories determined?
- Where does the data come from?
- How are they rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, a breadcrumb is a small text path that you usually see at the top of a page indicating your location on the site. Below is a simple illustration of breadcrumbs from a website.
3 common types of breadcrumbs in practices

- Hierarchy-based breadcrumbs

This is considered the most widely used and common type of breadcrumbs. In essence, hierarchy-based breadcrumbs tell web visitors where they’re in the site structure. Each text link is for a page that is one level higher than the one on its right.

- History-based breadcrumbs

Unlike the hierarchy-based breadcrumbs, the history-based (or path-based) ones have the same function as the browser back button. It allows users to quickly go back to the previous pages they visited with all of their selections intact.

- Attribute-based breadcrumbs

Along with the first breadcrumb type, attributed-based breadcrumbs are the 2 most widely used on an eCommerce site.

Comment: Thanks, but not really an answer to my questions. Check the 3 bullet points.